# Docker swarm node cannot see service

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-swarm, galera

I have try to run docker ps on Node 2 and 3 then it show nothing to me.
Like this image.

[image]

They show nothing but have container running on it.
I try to ping main node with this command.

```
    docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep etcd | awk {'print $1'}) ping mysql-galera
```

[image]

It can be reached on only node 1 so far.
Why other node can't see service that in the same swarm.
I've disable ufw to make sure no disturb from firewall.

Reference from this tutorial : https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-docker-introduction-docker-swarm-mode-and-multi-host-networking

Comment: `docker ps` returns the containers on that host (or, the daemon you're connected to). You want `docker service ps`.

Comment: @johnharris85 Why in the tutorial can be ping with that command from node2?

Comment: Because in their tutorial it has balanced a replica of mysql to each node (so there _is_ one running on docker2). In yours they have all started (for some reason) on docker1. Can you paste the command you used to start the service?